# update function in build in blender property

Tags: python, properties

When I create a new property, I can add an update function to execute every time it will be changed:

```
bpy.types.Scene.testprop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(update=update_func)
```

What if I want to call update_func on the update of build in blender property (for example mesh name). I found a similar question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/953/execute-function-on-object-property-change). But it does not work when I change the property from UI.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by 'build' in this context?

Comment: bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x  is property build in blender

Comment: Is that Impossible?