# Setting custom prop to Sequence

Tags: python

I need props in sequencer strips, to store data in each individual strip. One of the prop should link to other strips but:

I can’t make `PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Sequence)`. I get this error:

```
TypeError: PointerProperty(...) expected an RNA type derived from ID or ID Property Group
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "----", line 10, in <module>
  File "----", line 11, in StripSettings
ValueError: bpy_struct "ImageSequence" registration error: fakeinput1 could not register
```

Test script:

```
import bpy

#this works
bpy.types.Sequence.prop1 = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Scene)

#this not
bpy.types.Sequence.prop2 = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Sequence)
```

Any walkaround?

Comment: Sequence is a bpy_struct but not a ID.

Comment: @lemon and what can i do?

Comment: May be a workaround (?), but if not, the situation is similar for vertex groups (or uv maps or this kind of data). If you create a group, assign it to (say) a modifier, then the modifier stores a string/name only. So that, if you for instance change the group name, the modifier won't be updated.

Comment: Though, if you want to handle eventual changes, there is this kind of solutions https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/953/execute-function-on-object-property-change (a bit old, but updatable)

Comment: @lemon in this case I will get  allow script execution notice, but i want to make a add-on