# Use 2 color pickers to drive one value?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, drivers, properties

I'm currently driving the hair and body base color from a single property on the character below. However, I'd like the hair to be driven by another property as well. So that both properties (when changed) will drive the hair color to the exact color of only the changed property.

So, for example, I'd like to be able to do this:

1. Change (2)Diffuse Color for body and hair to Orange with one property
2. Change hair color to green with another property (body remains orange)
3. Change body *and* hair color to purple from original (2)Diffuse Color property

I would like these steps to be repeatable.

[image: Example]

Any idea how to pull this off?

I've been trying to find scripted expressions that only send a value when a driven property variable is changed. But if it remains the same it is not read.

Comment: If I were to do the 3 steps in order, would I go from 1) hair & body both orange to 2) hair green & body orange to 3) hair & body both purple  or would 3) leave the hair green because I changed it in 2?

Comment: @MartyFouts I would like to have hair and body both purple in step 3. I would also like these steps to be repeatable after that.

So if I wanted to (4) use the other property to change both the hair and body again, I could.

Comment: I think that [Message Bus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) is one right way to get the notifications you want; and [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/953/execute-function-on-object-property-change) discusses how to do that; except I can't for the life of me figure out how to use `datablock.path_resolve("property_name", False)` to get a valid value for a custom color picker property I added to world, no matter what I replace `datablock` with.

Comment: Ohhh, this is a great starting point though! I'll see what I can find out. Thanks for those links.

Comment: Ah, apparently this only works on custom properties you attach to `Scene` via python and not on custom properties you add with the add button

Comment: Thanks MartyFouts, I'll suppose I'll need to go ahead and use that solution here then! 

@Gorgious, custom properties added to an object in the properties panel (at the bottom) will be displayed in the item tab of the right viewport panel. ^_^  That's what I've done here.